# How to show a button at the end of an Android ListView

Tags: android, listview

I want to show a button at the end of an Android list view. How can I achieve this?

I don't want to stick it to the activity bottom using `alignparentbottom="true"`. Using `layout_below` does not work for me either.

My current XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_bg">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            android:cacheColorHint="#ff6a00"
            android:divider="#ff8f40"
            android:dividerHeight="1px" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:background="#676767"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnGetMoreResults"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
            android:text="Get more" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Like this: http://blog.maxaller.name/2010/05/attaching-a-sticky-headerfooter-to-an-android-listview/ ?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22319421/1128854

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You may want to use [ListView#addFooterView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) to add a `View` at the bottom of the `ListView`.

Comment: yes thanks man.
finally created dynamic button and then using 

               getListView().addFooterView ( DynamicButton);
now i can see button at the end of list view.

Answer (score 35):

I do it like this fixed button at the buttom of the screen

```
   <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_New" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_New"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/New"
        android:width="170dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

if ur using linearLayout then assign android:layout_weight="1" to the listview and dont assign weight for button it works

Comment: in my case, my button gets deformed to occupy the rest of the screen

Comment: ScrollView surrounding ListView (which scrolls too) isn't a good idea. You might find it starts to behave oddly.

Comment: @Thomas, my button was floating over the `<ListView>`. If this is your case, try removing from your `<Button>` this attribute: `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`

Answer (score 15):

You could do something like this:

```
final Button btnAddMore = new Button(this);
btnAddMore.setText(R.string.art_btn_moreIssues);
exArticlesList = (ExpandableListView) this.findViewById(R.id.art_list_exlist);
exArticlesList.addFooterView(btnAddMore);
```

Answer (score 7):

**1 If you want to add Button as the last element of the list view**

You must create custom [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) for your ListView which will create a view with a Button in the getView method. You should decide how to return your custom view for the last element, you can hardcode it (return element count +1 in getCount method and return custom view in getView when position > element count) or you can add element to the structure you will be taking data from (Array, Cursor etc.) and check if field of element have certain value

**2 If you want to add element below list view**

You should use android:layout_width attribute and make ListView and "empty" TextView (you should use it to show users that list is empty and View rendering is completed) layout_weight greater than buttons layout_weight

Check how it's done in Transdroids search Activity http://code.google.com/p/transdroid/source/browse/trunk/res/layout/search.xml

Comment: i am not talking about putting button in list view i want to place only single button at the bottom of list view thats it.
i think you have not understood my question properly.

Comment: To add any data to the ListView, you must create View that will be added. Object controlling what is shown in the ListView is its Adapter. Standard Adapters (SimpleAdapter, SimpleCursorAdapter, ArrayAdapter) can create only items from single layout, so you have to create your own Adapter (you cannot just add item to ListView like for ex. to swing JTable).

Comment: thanks for your reply.

but i am confused related to you are using word adding in list view. 
in my case i dont want to add button to list view but display after it where list view data ends. then why it has relationship with list view to make it custom?

Comment: Ok so maybe I've really not understood.
Do you want the button to be "in" the ListView (as the last element) or below the ListView and at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Edited answer to have both solutions.

Answer (score 6):

Use Footer view to list-view it work.

list_layout.xml :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:cacheColorHint="#ff6a00"
        android:divider="#ff8f40"
        android:dividerHeight="1px" />

</LinearLayout>
```

footerview.xml :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnGetMoreResults"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
        android:text="Get more" />
</FrameLayout>
```

and in Activity.java

```
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    FrameLayout footerLayout = (FrameLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footerview,null);
    btnPostYourEnquiry = (Button) footerLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnGetMoreResults);

    list.addFooterView(footerLayout);
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply Provide "layout_weight = 1" of ListView.

Example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:cacheColorHint="#ff6a00"
        android:divider="#ff8f40"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:dividerHeight="1px" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#ff8f40"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="Click"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This way the button is shown always below it, which might not be the desired solution.

Answer (score 3):

I came here looking for an answer first but found it somewhere else...

It's really easy, you just need to put weight 1 to the list inside a linear layout, the other textviews/buttons/etc don't need to have any weight value.

Here is an example: https://bitbucket.org/generalplus/android_development/src/5a892efb0551/samples/ApiDemos/res/layout/linear_layout_9.xml

Answer (score 0):

You could, of course, use a custom adapter and specify a footer item. But you could probably also get away with putting it at the bottom of a `ScrollView` and have the `ListView` stretch vertically to the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_bg">

  <ScrollView
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

      <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" 
          android:cacheColorHint="#ff6a00"
          android:divider="#ff8f40"
          android:dividerHeight="1px"
          />

      <RelativeLayout 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="50sp"
          android:background="#676767"
          android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button android:layout_width="100px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnGetMoreResults"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
            android:text="Get more" />

      </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

  </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: still no hope while doing this button does not displays neither layout i have increased layout height but still not visible.

Comment: hi...me too have facing same kind of problem,let me help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well... details of implementations are not so easy if you want to create a smooth "add more" button at the end of the list. So here is some code :

```
myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Show>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList) {

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if( position >= super.getCount()  )
            return buttonMore ;

        MyNormalView view = null; 
        if (convertView == null || convertView instanceof Button )
            view = new MyNormalView(getContext());
        else
            view = (MyNormalView) convertView;

        //customize view here with data
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
       return super.getCount()+1;
    }//met
};
```