# android How to limit list items display in ListView and a button show more

Tags: android, listview

I am getting data from Database and displaying using a custom list adapter in a ListView.

I need to display only 10 items in ListView. and after 10th item a button show with text "Show More", when click this button so show more 10 items from Database in listview.

How i can do this?

Please let me know with code example

Thanks

Comment: See this Link..[Link ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386593/how-to-show-a-button-at-the-end-of-an-android-listview

Answer (score 12):

In  Base Adapter, initially take i=10; then use this "i" in getCount() method of BaseAdapter.

```
public int getCount() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return i;
}
```

And in your "show more" Button click Increment the i, then call adapter.

Ex:

```
i=i+10;
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Short and accurate answer... +1 !

Comment: Being new to Java (from C#) I'm a little confused on how i gets to the BaseAdapter override. In my mind wouldn't you have to pass i in the constructor of NamesAdapter (referencing the pastebin sample)?