# cursor returns with 200 records and populates ListView

Tags: java, android

A SQLLite database is queried, and the results are displayed in a listView. Most of the times we are talking about... 5-10 records. But sometimes... 200+ records are retrieved. I do not want this many records to appear on the screen. How can I stop this and limit it to 15 maximum ?

Comment: paste code snippet where you are handling this

Answer (score 0):

Use a LIMIT clause in your SQLLite Query.

Comment: but i don't want to touch the query... is there anything else i can do ?

Comment: eventually... the client will need to see all that data... but just not at once

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071024/android-how-to-limit-list-items-display-in-listview-and-a-button-show-more, you'll need to modify your list adapter to only retrieve 10 records at once instead of them all, check Abhi's answer