# Add button as last element in Android ListView

Tags: mvvmcross

I've bound my list view to an observable collection but I want the last item in the list to be an 'add item' button.  I could do this in 'normal' Android with a custom adapter but I'm not sure how to do it with MvvmCross.

Comment: You could inherit from MvxAdapter and use the same technique as "normal" ?

Comment: could you not just use a footer for that?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this natively the same way you would on Android.  I would suggest you use the [ListView#addFooterView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) to add a `View` at the bottom of the `ListView`.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386593/how-to-show-a-button-at-the-end-of-an-android-listview) question.

There are other suggestions on there such as what you would do to have a fixed button that is always visible on the bottom of the screen.